# Model with collection - Html.ListBoxFor doesn't set selected items

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, .net-4.5, html.dropdownlistfor, html.listboxfor

This one is driving me crazy and before I loose my sane please help.

Summary of the issue:
My model "Thread" has collection of "ForumMessage", each ForumMessage has one Multi select drop down list. All I want to do is set the selected value based on values coming from Database. I have gone thru many threads but wasn't able to find the solution.

In case if you are aware of any such question please let me know and I will go thru them.

Below are my models

```
public class Thread
{
    public List<ForumMessage> Messages { get; set; }
    //Master list coming from DB
    public List<Classifications> AllClassifications { get; set; }
    public string Subject { get; set; }
    public int[] ThreadSelectedClassifications { get; set; }
}

public class ForumMessage
{
    public string MessageName { get; set; }
    public int[] SelectedClassifications { get; set; }
}

public class Classifications
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Below is my controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var thread = new Thread();
    thread.Messages = new List<ForumMessage>();

    thread.AllClassifications = new List<Classifications>() 
    { 
        new Classifications { ID = 1, Title = "One"   , Description = "One"   }, 
        new Classifications { ID = 2, Title = "Two"   , Description = "Two"   }, 
        new Classifications { ID = 3, Title = "Three" , Description = "Three" }, 
        new Classifications { ID = 4, Title = "Four"  , Description = "Four"  }, 
        new Classifications { ID = 5, Title = "Five"  , Description = "Five"  } 
    };
    thread.ThreadSelectedClassifications = new int[] { 2, 4 };
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        var post = new ForumMessage();
        post.SelectedClassifications = new int[] { 2, 4 };
        post.MessageName = i.ToString();
        thread.Messages.Add(post);
    }

    return View(thread);
```

Below is my view

```
@model MultiSelectDemo.Controllers.Thread
@foreach (var item in Model.Messages)
{
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            @*@Doesn't set the items selected *@
            @Html.ListBoxFor(m => item.SelectedClassifications, new SelectList(Model.AllClassifications, "ID", "Title"));
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4">
            @* Doesn't set the items selected  *@
            @Html.ListBoxFor(m => item.SelectedClassifications, new SelectList(Model.AllClassifications, "ID", "Title", item.SelectedClassifications));
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            @* Doesn't set the items selected  *@
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => item.SelectedClassifications, new SelectList(Model.AllClassifications, "ID", "Title", item.SelectedClassifications), new { @multiple = "multiple" })
        </div>
    </div>
}
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        This works.
        @Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.ThreadSelectedClassifications, new MultiSelectList(Model.AllClassifications, "ID", "Title"))
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: Sample Output]}

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`SelectList` only supports a single selected value, so in your code examples you're telling it to set the selected value as the option which has a value of the entire list of selected values. Since no such option exists, nothing is selected.

`MultiSelectList` on the other hand, allows passing an enumerable of selected values. If you use the right class, you'll be okay.

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(m => item.SelectedClassifications, new MultiSelectList(Model.AllClassifications, "ID", "Title", item.SelectedClassifications))
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have added this line too in my sample, if you see my last line in view this is exactly what I am using, but somehow it doesn't work inside collection so I think am missing something.

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that. I copied the line from your code intending to just add the "Multi" bit, but I copied the wrong line (where you weren't passing the selected values).

Comment: after much confusion for myself, I found the list of 'selected' items must be an array of ID's. So if you have a collection of the selected items: int[] selectedItemsToPassAsParameter = selectedItems.Select(item => item.ItemId).ToArray()