# MVC Dropdownlist selected values is not rebind on edit time?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using MVC dropdownlist,the selected value save is working Properly but the editfill time the selected dropdownlist value not Properly bind the selected value.

```
@model List<eProviderAdmin.Models.ServiceModel>

@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
@Html.ValidationSummary()

<div id="serviceDetails">
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++) {
   @Html.LabelFor(m => m[i].Discipline, new { @class = "label-header" })
   @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m[i].Discipline,   ((List<string>)ViewBag.GetDiscipline).Select(x => new SelectListItem() { Text = x, Value = x }), new   { id = "discipline" })
 }
 </div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately `DropDownListFor()` does not work correctly in a loop (its been reported as a bug but not yet fixed). You need to use a custom `EditorTempate` for the model, or you can set the `Selected` value of `SelectListItem`. [Refer this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27237683/model-with-collection-html-listboxfor-doesnt-set-selected-items/27237869#27237869) or [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26742155/dropdownlistfor-will-not-show-the-correct-selection/26752086#26752086)

Comment: What is `i` here? Have u debugged your code? Are you getting the value you wanna show as selected in `m[i].ServiceType`?

Comment: Can you post the two Edit controller methods as well, one for rendering the Edit form and the other processing the POST request back to the server?

Comment: @RahulSingh Please find my updated code.

Comment: I would use an editor template for this as mentioned above. The other thing is that you're setting them all to the same id. I can't remember whether this appends anything to the ids or not to differentiate them in this kind of loop. You might have to do it yourself.

Comment: @McGaz, `DropDownListFor()` generates the correct `name` and `id` attributes in a `for` loop. They are unique - `<select id="_0__Discipline" name="[0].Discipline" ..><select id="_1__Discipline" name="[1].Discipline" ..>` etc.